# Multiple calls to TWebModule.SendDirect

Tags: delphi

I have created a Web application which runs on Apache using TWebModule.  I have gotten a little "liberal" with the use of SendRedirect.  In one case I found I was calling SendRedirect and following it up with another SendRedirect call - all in the same method handler.  On my Test box, it would always redirect to the url of the first SendRedirect.  But on my production box, I discovered (much to my chagrin) that it was redirecting the browser to the url of the 2nd redirect.

I know the "Real" answer is that I should not be calling multiple SendRedirects.  But aside from that, does anyone have an explanation why in one environment it goes to the first SendRedirect while on another it goes to the 2nd?

Answer (score 1):

Check `Location:` header you get. You probably have different rewrite rules, or some other appache configuration options set.

Comment: I will check that.  Probably is something to do with the Apache Rewrites.